# Search for gaps between primes where each composite is divisible by increasing integers (2, 3, 4, ...)

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

Almost every text of number theory contains in its first chapters something similar to the following:

> For any integer n, the factorial n! is the product of all positive
> integers up to and including n. Then in the sequence
> $\,n!+2,\,n!+3,\,\ldots,\,n!+n\,$ the first term is divisible by 2,
> the second term is divisible by 3, and so on. Thus, this is a sequence
> of $\,n-1\,$ consecutive composite integers, and it must belong to a
> gap between primes having length at least $\,n$.

**But what about gaps between primes where each composite is divisible by increasing integers $\,(2,\,3,\,4,\,\ldots)$, without using factorials?**

Obviously, we shall say that $\,g_n\,$ is a "maximal gap", if $\,g_m\lt g_n\,$ for all $\,m\lt n$.

A list of the primes bounding the first maximal gaps (found searching into the first $\,10^7$ primes):

$(g=2)\;\;\;\;\;\;\,3,\,5\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(2|4)$

$(g=4)\;\;\;\;\;\;13,\,17\;\;\;\;\;\,(2|14,\,3|15,\,4|16)$

$(g=6)\;\;\;\;\;\;\,61,\,67\;\;\;\;\;(2|62,\,3|63,\,4|64,\,5|65,\,6|66)$

$(g=10)\;\;\;\;\;2521,\,2531\;\;\;\;\;(\ldots)$

$(g=12)\;\;\;\;\;471241,\,471253\;\;\;\;\;(\ldots)$

$(g=16)\;\;\;\;\;4324321,\,4324337\;\;\;\;\;(\ldots)$

$(g=18)\;\;\;\;\;110270161,\,110270179\;\;\;\;\;(\ldots)$

Here, instead, is a list of the frequencies ($f_g$) of all gaps (also not maximal) up to the first $\,10^7$ primes:

$(g=2)\;\;\;\;\;\;\,f_2=738597$

$(g=4)\;\;\;\;\;\;\,f_4=368781$

$(g=6)\;\;\;\;\;\;\,f_6=123052$

$(g=10)\;\;\;\;\;f_{10}=4136$

$(g=12)\;\;\;\;\;f_{12}=447$

$(g=16)\;\;\;\;\;f_{16}=17$

$(g=18)\;\;\;\;\;f_{18}=1$

**Some remarks: starting from $g=6$, in order to have satisfied the divisibility by 5, the first prime must be congruent to 1 (mod 20); $\,g\,$ seems always long $\,p-1$ (or it is just a coincidence?); $\,f_2\sim 2f_4\sim 6f_6$; maybe, there are infinitely many maximal gaps.**

**Could the previous remarks (except for the first) be explained in any way?**

Many thanks.

Comment: You can replace the factorials with $\text{lcm}(1, 2, \dots n)$ but it amounts to the same thing in the end. I don't see a particular reason to avoid them.

Comment: Surely, but $\,n!+1\,$ and $\,n!+1+n\,$ are not always both primes, as well as $\,[1,\,2,\,\ldots,\,n]+1\,$ and $\,[1,\,2,\,\ldots,\,n]+1+n\,$. So, my point of view is different.

Comment: Starting from $n=6$, it seems as the first prime must be congruent to 1 (mod 60) to me, which makes sense, as 2 | 60k +2, 3 | 60k + 3, etc., 60 is the lcm of 2,3,4 and 5, so from that point onward the lowest prime must be exactly 1 more than a multiple of it, in order for the divisibility property to hold.

Comment: You can argue also with the primorials to show that there are arbitary large prime gaps. Using factorials is just the easiest way to see it. Therefore, there also must be infinite many maximal gaps. But for no even gap is known whether infinite many pairs exist having this gap , and it is neither known whether every even number occurs as a gap.

Comment: It is however conjectured that every even gap occurs infinite many often. Not sure about the conjectured longterm frequencies. By the way, an impressing result is that there are infinite many prime gaps not exceeding $246$ , so at least one of the even numbers upto $246$ occurs infinite many often as a gap.